# Search box with a dropdown content from database and add the selected item beside the search box when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pasted below is my requirement. I want a search box which shows content as a dropdown box (the data will be fetched from database) and when I click on that, the selected item should get appended beside it with a cross button can be used to delete them(delete them from selected item list).

[image: Sample image]

I tried one animated search [box](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_anim_search) which expands the search to an extent. Can I add the drop-down search thing into this type of search box?

Could anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: w2ui's Multi Select could be what you're looking for: http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!fields/fields-4

Comment: Multi select part is what am looking as functionality but instead of adding the selected item inside the box, can I add it outside the box?